# Derivative of Arctangent with definition of derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition

I can't find the derivative of arctangent with definition of derivative.
Here's my way:
$\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$ is a definition of derivative with limit. If we define $f(x)=\arctan(x)$, then we get:
$$\left[\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{\arctan(x+\Delta x)-\arctan(x)}{\Delta x}\right]=\left[\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{1+x(x+\Delta x)}\right)}{\Delta x}\right].$$ But I don't know how to continue. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that $\tan x\approx x$ for small $x$ values?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if I can use this because I want to make the proof rigorously.

Comment: Also, yes if we accept that, derivative of arctangent come without rush

Comment: Why do you think that the usage of $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}=1$ is unrigorous?

Comment: I don't maybe because I solved for sin, cos, tan, cot with the definition and I haven't seen anything like that. But if you all saying that it's rigorous, I can accept and use that.

Comment: This form is no different from $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$, which you use in differentiating $\sin x$ and other trigonometric functions

Comment: Thank you, I won't forget this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{1+x(x+\Delta x)}\right)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{\arctan\left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{1+x^2}\right)}{\Delta x}$$
Now let's introduce the variable $u$ by $$\tan u=\dfrac{\Delta x}{1+x^2}$$
Then $$\Delta x=(1+x^2)\tan u$$and your limit is $$\lim_{u\to\ 0}\frac{\arctan(\tan u)}{(1+x^2)\tan u}=\lim_{u\to\ 0}\frac{u}{(1+x^2)\tan u}=\frac1{1+x^2}\frac1{\lim_{u\to\ 0}\frac{\tan u} u}=\frac1{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Did you just plug 0 at the begging in $\arctan(x)$?

Comment: You can always neglect $\Delta x$ when you add it to $x$, if $|x|>0$. If $x=0$, then you just have $\arctan(\Delta x)$, which you can still write it as the right hand side of my first equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\arctan x,\,y+\Delta y=\arctan(x+\Delta x)$ so$$\begin{align}\arctan^\prime x&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\arctan (x+\Delta x)-\arctan x}{\Delta x}\\&=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\tan(y+\Delta y)-\tan y}\\&\stackrel{\star}{=}\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\tan(y+\Delta y)-\tan y}\\&\stackrel{\dagger}{=}\frac{1}{1+\tan^2y}\\&=\frac{1}{1+x^2},\end{align}$$where $\star$ uses the continuity of $\arctan x$ and $\dagger$ uses $\frac{d}{dy}\tan y=1+\tan^2y$, which can also be proved from first principles:$$\begin{align}\tan^\prime y&=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{\tan(y+\Delta y)-\tan y}{\Delta y}\\&=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{\frac{\tan y+\tan\Delta y}{1-\tan y\tan\Delta y}-\tan y}{\Delta y}\\&=\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{(1+\tan^2y)\tan\Delta y}{\Delta y}\frac{1}{1-\tan y\tan\Delta y}\\&=(1+\tan^2y)\underbrace{\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{\tan\Delta y}{\Delta y}}_1\underbrace{\lim_{\Delta y\to0}\frac{1}{1-\tan y\tan\Delta y}}_1,\end{align}$$where we use $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\tan h}{h}=1,\,\lim_{h\to0}\tan h=0$.

Comment: That's so much help, I think I can apply same procedure for all arc function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{\Delta x\to\ 0} \frac{\arctan(x+\Delta x)-\arctan x}{\Delta x} = \lim_{u\,\to\,v} \frac{u-v}{\tan u - \tan v} 
$$
Here we have $u = \arctan(x+\Delta x)$ so $\tan u = x+ \Delta x$ and so on.

Why is it that $u\to v$ as $\Delta x\to 0\text{?}$ In effect this says the arctangent function is continuous. That can only follow from properties of the tangent function on the interval $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2).$

Then
$$
\lim_{u\,\to\,v} \frac{u-v}{\tan u - \tan v} = \frac 1 {\sec^2 v} = \frac 1 {1+\tan^2 v} = \frac 1 {1+x^2.}
$$
Here of course you need to know how to differentiate the tangent function before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the straight function, find derivative and notice that

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{dx/dy}=$$

So
$$x= \tan(y)$$

In the way you have obtained d.c. you can also find:

$$ \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \sec^2 y ={1+x^2}$$

$$ \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{1}{\sec^2}  =\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for contribution, but the question is without using implicit function derivative